# How to make bar chart cover multiple labels?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a demo example which looks like below

[image]

I have two datasets the one is bar and the other is line,

```
 datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Line chart',
        type:'line',
        borderColor:'red',
          data: [
           1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4
        ],
        fill:false,
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
          label: '# of Votes',
        type:'Bar chart',
          data: [
          12,null,null,null,13,null,null,null,17,null,null,null,23,null,null,null
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
        ]
```

Line chart represents each day and bars represent each month.I want a bar to cover 4 labels(to point that its monthly).So my desired behavior would be like below

[image]

How can I achieve this?My JsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/jn52swdo/

Comment: I guess you forgot your fiddle example because you gave the basic fiddle that pops up when you google for chartjs fiddle

Comment: @LeeLenalee oh sorry thats my fault.I updated the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a second `x` axis where you link to.

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Month-1", "", "", "", "", "", "Month-2", "", "", "", "", "", "Month-3", "", "", "", "", "", "Month-4", "", "", "", "", ""],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
      borderWidth: 1,
      xAxisID: 'x2',
      categoryPercentage: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {},
      x2: {
        display: false,
        labels: ["", "", "", ""]
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```